# I accidentally ran "sudo umount -a" and now have no access to anything

Tags: filesystem, root, umount

Now I can't remount anything and get access back. How can I fix it?

`sudo` returns

> ```
> sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a filesystem with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS filesystem without root privileges?
> ```

`mount` returns

> ```
> mount: failed to read mtab: No such file or directory
> ```

If I try to open anything new I get the message

> ```
> Failed to execute child 
> Failed to open PTY: No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: The downside of the fall of /etc/mtab is /dev got unmounted.

Comment: You're lucky. I once did `rm -rf *` in the `/` directory when I thought I was in a subdirectory.

Comment: No worries (in this case).  The most important lesson: be very careful of what you do as the root user (i.e. when using `sudo`).  As @O.Jones mentioned, there are worse things you could have done than this.

Comment: How could you do that? On my newer system it outputted "/dev: target is busy." - same for many others inc. "/run" and the system is usable.

Answer (score 93):

Just reboot the machine. It is just temporarily and the permanent configuration in `/etc/fstab` is restored upon reboot.

Comment: Reboot worked. I have much to learn...

Comment: When in doubt, turn it off and then on again.  (With certain exceptions.)

Answer (score 25):

Whenever you are on a situation like this on Linux, if you want to do a safe reboot, there is the "Magic SysRq key" + REISUB:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

You need to press: `Alt + SysRq` and while keeping that pressed type:

- `r`: The kernel takes `r`aw control of the keyboard (from X or Wayland)
- `e`: T`e`rminate all running programs
- `i`: K`i`ll all programs left (except init)
- `s`: `S`ync (flush data to disk)
- `u`: `u`nmount (remounts all filesystems readonly)
- `b`: re`b`oot

Keep a few seconds between each typed letter for each of the tasks to complete.

This is a clean way of directly telling the linux kernel to restart.

Since you had unmounted all the file systems, the sync and unmount do not make much sense to me, however it is easier to remember the whole sequence than to apply only the parts you need.

Comment: REISUB is easier to remember as BUSIER backwards.

Comment: Reboot Even If System's Utterly Broken

Comment: @cjm I think the difficulty with getting it right has little to do with remembering the “REISUB” part, but the alt+SysRq one (or, what key SysRq even is, because it's by no means labelled on all keyboards).

Comment: In Spanish keyboards SysRq is labelled as PetSis (Petición Sistema). It's a rather unknown key to most users, so it may be difficult to find in some keyboards.

Comment: How would you do it remotely over SSH?

Comment: `S` is renundant because `U` also does that (of course, you should still wait until the message "Emergency remount complete"). I also don't think `I` is necessary (the programs will get killed when the computer reboots anyway).

Comment: @CanadianLuke I'm not OP, but, as far as I remember, you can echo/cat the commands into `/proc/sysrq-trigger` (as root)

Comment: @CanadianLuke Is it even possible to be still connected to the machine if you do what OP has done remotely?

Comment: @gerrit I was able to do it on another Linux machine over SSH.... Just saying... :P

Answer (score -2):

To avoid rebooting, I believe running `sudo mount -a` should fix it, as it will then run the mounts specified in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: As per the question, `sudo`  produces `sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a filesystem with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS filesystem without root privileges?` error.